# xrandr: How to check if mirroring screens

Tags: bash, xrandr

What's a clean way to check if my monitors are being mirrored or not with xrandr?

**Background** 
I'm using polybar and as of now I have a script that launches an extra polybar if my second monitor is connected. Problem is that when I'm mirroring I don't want to launch that second bar. Here's my code if somebody's curious:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Terminate already running bar instances
killall -q polybar

# Wait until the processes have been shut down
while pgrep -u $UID -x polybar >/dev/null; do sleep 1; done

# Launch bar 
polybar main_bar -r & 

my_laptop_external_monitor=$(xrandr --query | grep 'HDMI-1')
if [[ $my_laptop_external_monitor = *connected* ]]; then
    polybar external_bar &
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran `xrandr --listmonitors` on my system, with and without cloned monitors:

*Not cloned*:

```
Monitors: 2
 0: +*DisplayPort-0 1920/598x1080/336+1920+0  DisplayPort-0
 1: +HDMI-0 1920/598x1080/336+0+0  HDMI-0
```

*Cloned*

```
Monitors: 2
 0: +*DisplayPort-0 1920/598x1080/336+0+0  DisplayPort-0
 1: +HDMI-0 1920/598x1080/336+0+0  HDMI-0
```

The only difference is the output's position within the screen, `1920+0` vs `0+0`. When the monitor is mirrored, the position of both monitors are the same (both `0+0`).

If you mirror your monitors this way <sup>1</sup>, a good way to check if a monitor is mirrored is to compare their positions in the ouput of `xrandr --listmonitors`.

I don't think there is a cleaner way than this. As far as I can tell, you don't actually mirror or clone monitors you only set their positions inside to screen in such a way that they overlap and when rendering, both monitors show the same picture because they're at the same location. That's why there isn't really a straightforward way to test for mirrored screens.

---

<sup>1</sup>**Side Note:** The monitor was cloned with the following command

```sh
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --same-as DisplayPort-0
```

Comment: Okay so if I understood correctly the position will then be `0+0` for both when mirroring _no matter_ the resolution of the external monitor (The resolution of the external monitor I'm using varies)

Comment: @MattiasJohnson Yes, this is very likely, especially if you have at most two monitors, but you would have to test this yourself to be absolutely sure. The resolution of the external monitor should not matter since it would be scaled to the resolution of the main monitor anyway.